# Can anyone explain the test case for the puzzle "Repairing Roads"?

Tags: algorithm, graph, programming-languages

I am trying to solve the following puzzle. I am confused by one of the test case.

Here is the problem:

The country of Byteland contains of N cities and N - 1 bidirectional roads between them such that there is a path between any two cities. The roads in Byteland were built long ago and now they are in need of repair. You have been hired to repair all the roads. You intend to do this by dispatching robots on some of the roads. Each robot will repair the road he is currently on and then move to one of the adjacent unrepaired roads. After repairing that, he will move to another adjacent unrepaired road, repair that and so on.

Two roads are adjacent if they have the same city at one of their endpoints. For the process to be efficient, no two robots will can ever repair the same road, and no road can be visited twice. What is the least number of robots needed to accomplish the task?

Input:
The first line contains the number of test cases T. T test cases follow. The first line of each testcase contains N, the number of cities in Byteland. The cities are numbered 0..N - 1. The following N - 1 lines contain the description of the roads. The ith line contains two integers ai and bi, meaning that there is a road connecting cities with numbers ai and bi.

Output:
Output T lines, one corresponding to each test case containing the required answer for that test case.

Constraints:
1 <= T <= 20
1 <= N <= 10000
0 <= ai,bi < N

Now bolow is the test case that I'm confused:

> 1
> 15
> 0 11
> 1 7
> 1 11
> 2 11
> 2 14
> 3 4
> 4 10
> 4 13
> 4 8
> 5 13
> 6 10
> 7 9
> 8 11
> 11 12
>
> The correct answer is 2, but why?

Comment: Is this homework?  If so, please use the `homework` tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note the definition of "adjacent road" here - you're not looking for a traversal where the robot passes each road only once.

Using the definition, you have four "terminal roads" in this graph, 6 10, 5 13, 2 14 and 7 9 - these can't be in the middle of a sequence since they have only one adjacent road. This is a first indication that you can get by with two robots (starting in two of these and ending in the other two). Note then that Byteland is almost split into two subcountries with 4 8 11 the only connecting road, so you can't have two robots passing between the halves, making it natural that one robot will repair each half.

From there, it's fairly trivial to construct a sample traversal (colors - robots, numbers -sequence), of course there are many since you can reverse start/end and shuffle some order in between

[image: Example solution for test case]

All due to [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) and my visual cortex, but you weren't asking for the general solution anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It is mentioned in this question that no two robots will ever repair the same road, and no road can be visited twice . 

1> if the distance of 
 the endpoint of one of the branch is greater than one than it is needed to send robot in that direction .

2> distance of endpoint from any vertex =1 then not require any extra robot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7zm6.png